# Python. Crear listas con datos que introduce el usuario

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en python y quisiera saber como crear dos listas de n datos ingresadas por el usuario para luego operar con sus elementos.

Desde ya gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Con qué versión de Python trabajas?

Comment: Que tal, estoy trabajando con Python 3.7.2

Comment: Hola Tony, bienvenido. ¿Cómo quieres que el usuario ingrese las listas? ¿En una sola línea separadas por espacios o comas, o en sucesivas líneas? En el segundo caso ¿cómo sabes cuántos datos va a introducir? ¿se lo preguntas antes o hay un valor "especial" (por ejemplo 0, o -1, o "FIN") que el usuario debe introducir para indicar que ya no hay mas? ¿De qué tipo son los datos? Te recomiendo leer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para consejos sobre cómo preguntar.

Comment: Hola, la verdad no me han especificado nada de eso, el ejercicio que tengo dice lo siguiente. "Elabore un programa que tome dos listas ingresadas por el usuario y que calcule la suma de los elementos que se no se repiten". Esa es toda la instrucción y no me han especificado nada más.

Answer (score 1):

@Tony

Si entendi bien lo que esperas lograr este codigo te ayudara:

```
#Creamos 2 listas vacias
lista1 = []
lista2 = []

#Preguntamos al usuario cuantos datos desea integrar
cantidad = int(input("Cuantos datos desea agregar: "))

#Greneramos un cilo para que se repitan las preguntas mientras la cantidad sea mayor que 0
while cantidad>0:
    #Pedimos que indique en que lista deea guardar su dato
    lista = input("En que lista desea ingresas sus datos \n1) Lista1 \n2) Lista2 \n")
    #Pedimos el dato
    dato = input("Ingrese sus datos: ")
    #Comprobamos la decision del usuario para saber en que lista se guardara el dato
    if lista == 1:
        lista1.append(str(dato))
    else:
        lista2.append(str(dato))
    #Quitamos de a uno en uno los intentos de el valor inicial que l usuario indico para poder detener el ciclo
    cantidad-=1
#Finalmente imprimimos el contenido de las listas
print("Contenido lista1:\n",lista1)
```

**Lo que se propone:**

1. En el anterior código preguntamos al usuario un numero determinado de datos que desea ingresar para ambas listas
2. Después de eso el usuario decidirá en que lista se añadirá ese dato.
3. Una vez que llegue a 0 el numero de datos que ingresaría el programa finalizara mostrando el contenido de ambas listas